# why if statement with e.preventDefault ? - drag and drop javascript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, preventdefault

I'm following this example to make a javascript html5 DnD (drag and drop): http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

To prevent the default behavior for some browsers the default event is prevented. I understand the need. But why is there also an if statement?

```
function handleDragOver(e) { 
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
  }
```

// Why this if statement?, 
To me it seems double: 
if it is already there (if true), do it again...?

Thanks for anyone who has some time to explain this to a newbie in JavaScript.

Thanks!

Comment: _"To me it seems double"_, its not double, `if(e.preventDefault)` isn't executing that function, just checking its existence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first call isn't actually calling the function, but simply checking to see if it is defined. The code is basically asking "is the `e.preventDefault()` method defined?" and then executing it if it is:

```
// Is preventDefault() currently defined?
if (e.preventDefault) {
     // Then do it.
     e.preventDefault(); 
}
```

**Possible Reasoning**

The likely reason that this exists is that [support for `event.preventDefault()` wasn't added in Internet Explorer until IE9](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975460(v=vs.85).aspx), so code similar to the following may have been more common during those dark, pre-IE9 days :

```
// An example of a pre-IE9 check for preventing default events
(event.preventDefault) ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
```

Comment: Hi Rion ,Thanks a lot for the explanation. I see now how it is checking if the method is defined. So in the case of pre IE9 it would do the default action i guess? Then what does this check prevent ?

Comment: I believe so, as `e.preventDefault()` wouldn't be defined and thus the if-statement would never be executed, so things would go on as usual. [As Halcyon mentioned in his response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36920752/557445), the actual `e` in this scenario may not even exist at all in some older versions of IE.

Comment: I see. indeed. Thanks for the insight both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Usually statements like this have to do with browser compatibility. For instance some browser might not have implemented the `preventDefault()` function. That being said, I don't know of any browser that has this problem.

Older versions of Internet Explorer would *not* pass the event object as a parameter but instead the event was in the global scope (ie `window.event`). But this code does not guard against that because if `e` is undefined `if(e.preventDefault)` will throw an exception.

Another candidate reason is that `handleDragOver` is called from more than just the eventlistener. In the sample code this is not the case but perhaps there was a need for this at some point. I would consider this to be bad practise, and eventlistener should have only one input parameter and it should always be an event.

I'm confident you can remove the `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks Halcyon!  You mean that the if check is not really preventing anything since it would throw an exception anyways if not present right?